# Replacing field name with variable in select query

Tags: mysql, sql, variables

I want to replace field name with variable to get data from table in PHP and MySQL.

```
select * from demo where variable-1
```

instead of `select * from demo where fieldname=1`

as there are more than 50 fieldname to be chosen from drowpdown.

Comment: You have to use **`Dynamic Query`** for your desired **`Output`**!

Answer (score 5):

**Variables will not work** on `field names` as well as `table Names`. The only time it will do is when you are creating *dynamic sql*, eg

```
SET @variableName = 'fieldname';
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM demo WHERE `', @variableName, '` = 1');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

- [Dynamic SQL (*Prepared Statements*)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)

Comment: Wouldn't you surround the `@variableName` with backticks in case it might be a reserved word?

Comment: @inhan yes, good point! actually you can alternatively use alias even if's a reserved keyword. `:D`

Comment: @inhan ex, `SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM demo a WHERE a.', @variableName, ' = 1');`

Comment: Yeah I almost forgot about that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)

```
delimiter // 
CREATE PROCEDURE dynamic(IN tbl CHAR(64), IN col CHAR(64))
BEGIN
    SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT ',col,' FROM ',tbl );
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
END
//
delimiter ;
```